# CSS hovering works only on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

the CSS excerpt:

```
ul li:hover {
    background: orange;
}
```

the php excerpt:

```
while($w3school = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li id='".$w3school['id']."'>" . $w3school['LastName'] . "</li>";
}
```

the html excerpt surrounding the list points above:

```
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Javascript mouseover as replacement for css - doesn't work either:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('#myUL');

function whatClicked(evt) {
   evt.target.style.backgroundColor="blue";
}

ul.addEventListener("mouseover", whatClicked, false);
```

To not overload this question ask for more code of needed. But except for the ajax call that shouldn't be relevant here, that's all.

So, the problem is that the background changes, but only when being clicked on. I find that it connects to the php as it works well without the database connection. But why?

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the element in your dev tool pop-up and emulate the `:hover` state? Are your style rules appearing? And if so, is it being negated by another rule, with more specificity?

Comment: The style guides in the dev tool pup-up don't change when hovering with the mouse.

Comment: If your style rule doesn't appear there, while emulating this state, then according to the browser it doesn't exist. If these rules exist in an external stylesheet that is being loaded, you should see them appear in the dev tool pop-up, whether they are being overwritten or not. YOu can verify that this rule exists in your external stylesheet in your Sources panel, by finding the stylesheet loaded on the page and searching for the rule in the source code. If this stylesheet can't be found on the server, you will notice a 404 error in your console. Can you could provide a link to the site?

Comment: yeah that's the site http://dbtestsite.is-great.net/?i=2 and i said it wrong, the styling works. BackgroundColor etc. just the hovering doesn't. You have to change the option button to YEA ! and then a list from the database appears. And when clicked on it changes the BG to orange. Which should happen if hovered.

Comment: JS mouseover as replacement doesn't work either

Comment: Ok man, because you have `background-color: blue` declared as an inline style rule, it will always over-qualify any external style rule. I'm loathe to using the `!important` declaration, but in this case it'll be necessary, e.g: `ul li:hover {
    background: orange !important;
}` The ideal solution would be to have that inline rule declared externally with the `:hover` rule, this will negate the need to use the `!important` declaration.

Comment: I deleted the [background-color: blue] and the external [ul li:hover {
    background: orange;}] should come to place. But it doesn't. And I've tried to create a mouseover event - which as 'click' does work - but doesn't react when being hovered. It seems like the php is somehow taking away the hovering capability.

Comment: `ul.addEventListener("mouseover", whatClicked, false);` your event listener is firing this function (`whatClicked`) on hover, which triggers the snippet `evt.target.style.backgroundColor="blue";` effectively adding the style rule inline (which is blue) and by extension overriding your external style. Why don't you remove this event listener and gauge the results.

Comment: I've rmoved the script link and it's the same. I have added a new php file with no link to the other css. And it displays a table on load. And the same happens. Hovering only happens when being clicked on. I guess I have to set up a new sub domain and retry with a neutral php file and script.

Comment: You only need to remove 'ul.addEventListener("mouseover", whatClicked, false);' from your script, because when you hover over (`mouseover`) the element it fires the function `whatClicked` which turns the background color to blue. That's it man - it boils down to this: the inline rule is over-qualifying your external rule, and that inline rule comes from the javascript event listener which fires on `mouseover` (hover) and triggers the function which applies that inline style. I'm going to leave it that - good luck! I know you'll come right eventually!

Comment: The thing is you're right, but it still wouldn't work, because as it turns out it works all fine if i load the page from the php file including html. When I load it via ajax it all goes down. I don't know why, but there is the problem.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve here? If you can tell me the whole flow then I'll be happy to help you with the solution.

Comment: I am trying to use a database (insert, read ...), the normal stuff. The thing is I am using the php file as index.php and so could resolve the issue above, which was to hover over a database retrieved element. But now I am at the point where I need to load another php file externally with ajax and it doesn't work.

Comment: function showUser() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

Comment: The above ajax request uses a php file that for itself works fine, but when I load it with above request it doesn't do anything.